# How to initiate widgets through tk/tcl

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI. I am using images as tags.
The rectangles indicate the action area, where i can launch my widget or app by dragging my tags. How to do that?

I have made a canvas with rectangles and i have implemented the drag and drop feature.

I have implemented the canvas with rectangles using pack() and i have used the drag and drop functionality

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

class DragAndDrop:
    def __init__(self, boxes, apps, width=1920, height=1080, bg="white"):
    self.photos = []
    self.__apps = {}
    self.__boxes = set()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=width, height=height, bg=bg)
    self.canvas.pack()

    for box in boxes:
        self.__boxes.add(
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                box["x1"], box["y1"], box["x2"], box["y2"],
                width=box["width"], fill=box["fill"]
            )
        )

    for app in apps:
        self.photos.append(PhotoImage(file=app["img"]))
        self.__apps[(
            self.canvas.create_image(app["x"], app["y"], image=self.photos[-1])
        )] = app["cmd"]

    self.__move = False
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_movement)
    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_movement)
    self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.movement)

def run(self):
    self.root.mainloop()

def start_movement(self, event):
    self.initi_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    self.initi_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    self.movingimage = self.canvas.find_closest(
        self.initi_x, self.initi_y, halo=5
    )

    if self.movingimage[0] in self.__apps:
        self.__move = True

def stop_movement(self, event):
    self.__move = False
    overlaps = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*self.canvas.bbox(self.movingimage))

    if len(overlaps) > 1 and not self.movingimage[0] in self.__boxes and \
       any(x in self.__boxes for x in overlaps):
        subprocess.Popen(self.__apps[self.movingimage[0]])

def movement(self, event):
    if self.__move:
        end_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        end_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        deltax = end_x - self.initi_x
        deltay = end_y - self.initi_y
        self.initi_x = end_x
        self.initi_y = end_y
        self.canvas.move(self.movingimage, deltax, deltay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
boxes = (
    {"x1": 618, "y1": 100, "x2": 693, "y2": 175, "width": 5, "fill": "white"},
    {"x1": 693, "y1": 100, "x2": 768, "y2": 175, "width": 5, "fill": "white"},
    {"x1": 618, "y1": 175, "x2": 693, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "green"},
    {"x1": 693, "y1": 175, "x2": 768, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "green"},
    {"x1": 618, "y1": 250, "x2": 693, "y2": 325, "width": 5, "fill": "blue"},
    {"x1": 693, "y1": 250, "x2": 768, "y2": 325, "width": 5, "fill": "blue"},
    {"x1": 618, "y1": 325, "x2": 693, "y2": 400, "width": 5, "fill": "yellow"},
    {"x1": 693, "y1": 325, "x2": 768, "y2": 400, "width": 5, "fill": "yellow"},
    {"x1": 543, "y1": 175, "x2": 618, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "dark orange"},
    {"x1": 468, "y1": 175, "x2": 543, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "dark orange"},
    {"x1": 768, "y1": 175, "x2": 843, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "red"},
    {"x1": 843, "y1": 175, "x2": 918, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "red"},
)

apps = (
    {"x": 125, "y": 125, "img": "chrome.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"},
    {"x": 125, "y": 225, "img": "firefox.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"},
    {"x": 125, "y": 325, "img": "np++.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"},
    {"x": 125, "y": 425, "img": "word.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe"},
    {"x": 200, "y": 125, "img": "excel.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"},
    {"x": 200, "y": 225, "img": "ppt.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE"},
    {"x": 200, "y": 325, "img": "outlook.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"},
    {"x": 200, "y": 425, "img": "access.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE"},
    {"x": 50, "y": 125, "img": "onenote.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE"},
    {"x": 50, "y": 225, "img": "pub.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSPUB.EXE"},
    {"x": 50, "y": 325, "img": "vlc.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"},
    {"x": 50, "y": 425, "img": "ccl.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe"},

)

dnd = DragAndDrop(boxes, apps)
dnd.run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! By "launch widget or app", do you mean you want to start a new Python process of some sort? Which applications do you want to launch, specifically (where are they located, what behavior do you expect, etc)? Further clarification would be helpful. Also, I'd look into using lists and loops so you don't have to put numbers after each item by hand and you can scale to arbitrarily many.

Comment: OK, that helps. So, when you drag and drop a rectangle on a box, which app should open? Does it matter which box the icon touches?

Comment: Please don't vandalize the title of your post. If you make drastic modifications, it makes the post less useful to future visitors. If you have a new question to raise, post it separately.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a very cool project, and welcome to SO!

---

## Refactoring

Before moving ahead to add new logic, it's well worth the time to clean up your current code.

#### Lists and loops

Right now, the approach of naming variables as `image0`, `image1` ... `image12` is very rigid and unscalable. If you need to add another box or application icon, you're basically stuck rewriting all of your code to accommodate the change. As for scalability, what if you want 50, 100 or 1000 applications? That's going to be a *lot* of typing!

This is why [lists](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) and similar array-like structures were invented. The idea is a single container to put like items into. You can [loop](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/) over the list and do something to each item in the list. I'm not going to go into a full tutorial on lists and loops, but they're essential tools for any programming task, so it's imperative to learn how to use them in order to make forward progress as a coder.

As a concrete example in your immediate code, use one variable, `images = []`, in place of `image1` ... `image12`. Inside the braces, add your image data, then access one with `images[n]` where `n` is the index of the image you want to work on. You can loop over them with constructs like:

```
for image in images:
    # do something with this image
```

You can also use tuples as lists that cannot be changed (I use tuples throughout this application--similar to lists, but they look like `apps = ()`).

#### Dictionaries

While lists are horizontal and store like items in a collection, [dictionaries](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) are vertical, or group related but distinct properties together into a single entity. In your code, an "app" entity is described by a few strings and numbers as follows:

```
{
    "x": 125, 
    "y": 125, 
    "img": "np++.png", 
    "cmd": r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
}
```

I make lists of these dictionaries to store data about where I want my boxes and apps to show up and what command and image (or color/width in the case of boxes) is associated with each one.

#### Sets

[Sets](https://realpython.com/python-sets/) are useful for checking membership. In this application, we need to determine which canvas entities are application icons and which are drop boxes. I used sets for performing this tagging logic, with two disjoint sets containing ids for apps and boxes, respectively.

#### Encapsulation

Currently, your code has related logic in many different places. The class accesses a lot of data contained in the global state. This is unsafe: if you change something about the global state, you may well cause bugs or break the class. Try to write functions and classes with strong [encapsulation](https://pythonspot.com/encapsulation/) and as few dependencies between components as possible. In this application, it's possible to neatly pack everything into the `DragAndDrop` class and simply pass in the parameters to tell it how to operate. That way, the caller can only engage with the class' available public functions, and failures are easily isolated and predictable.

#### Style cleanup

By [Python convention](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/), use `snake_case` for variable and function names and `UpperCamelCase` for classes. When posting code, ensure indentation is correct since Python uses indentation to determine which block scope each line of code is in.

Aside from the `dnd` class which I renamed to `DragAndDrop`, your variable names are clear, which is commendable!

---

## Adding new behavior

After refactoring and setting up data structures, we can begin adding the new functionality freely.

#### Collision

While your drag and drop functionality is beautiful, there is no code yet to determine when an app icon is dropped onto a box. This is a bit tricky: we can use `canvas.find_overlapping()` to check for overlap, but we need to make sure that the icon is dropped onto a box rather than another icon. Once movement stops, we can call this function to do this:

```
def stop_movement(self, event):
    self.__move = False
    overlaps = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*self.canvas.bbox(self.movingimage))

    if len(overlaps) > 1 and not self.movingimage[0] in self.__boxes and \
       any(x in self.__boxes for x in overlaps):
        subprocess.call(self.__apps[self.movingimage[0]])
```

The function uses some of the data structures I talked about earlier to establish the relationships between the different entities.

#### Creating and killing processes

Use `subprocess.call()` to make a system call to open a new process and block until it closes. You can use `subprocess.Popen()` if you want to open multiple applications without blocking to wait until they finish. Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for more information.  I used a dictionary to map app ids with the correct command to pass into `subprocess.Popen()`.

Per your additional request, call `kill()` on the created subprocess to kill it. I save all of this information in a `self.__app` dictionary, but it could probably use a refactor to a class for proper encapsulation because apps are accruing their own properties and behavioral logic.

---

## Code

Note that this is just an initial refactor with the new behavior added; there is always room for improvement, and some of the choices I made in terms of organizing data may not be to your liking, so I recommend exploring further and tweaking to taste. I also only bothered adding two text editor applications, but you can add to the `apps` tuple as many apps as you like to test further.

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

class DragAndDrop:
    def __init__(self, boxes, apps, width=1920, height=1080, bg="white"):
        self.photos = []
        self.__apps = {}
        self.__boxes = set()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=width, height=height, bg=bg)
        self.canvas.pack()

        for box in boxes:
            self.__boxes.add(
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                    box["x1"], box["y1"], box["x2"], box["y2"], 
                    width=box["width"], fill=box["fill"]
                )
            )

        for app in apps:
            self.photos.append(PhotoImage(file=app["img"]))
            self.__apps[(
                self.canvas.create_image(app["x"], app["y"], image=self.photos[-1])
            )] = {"cmd": app["cmd"], "running": False, "proc": None}

        self.__move = False
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_movement)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_movement)
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.movement)

    def run(self):    
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_movement(self, event):
        self.initi_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.initi_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        self.movingimage = self.canvas.find_closest(
            self.initi_x, self.initi_y, halo=5
        )

        if self.movingimage[0] in self.__apps:
            self.__move = True

    def stop_movement(self, event):
        self.__move = False
        overlaps = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*self.canvas.bbox(self.movingimage))
        app = self.movingimage[0]

        if len(overlaps) > 1 and app not in self.__boxes and not self.__apps[app]["running"] \
           and any(x in self.__boxes for x in overlaps):
            self.__apps[app]["proc"] = subprocess.Popen(self.__apps[app]["cmd"])
            self.__apps[app]["running"] = True
        elif app not in self.__boxes and self.__apps[app]["running"] \
           and not any(x in self.__boxes for x in overlaps):
            self.__apps[app]["proc"].kill()
            self.__apps[app]["running"] = False

    def movement(self, event):
        if self.__move:
            end_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            end_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            deltax = end_x - self.initi_x
            deltay = end_y - self.initi_y
            self.initi_x = end_x
            self.initi_y = end_y
            self.canvas.move(self.movingimage, deltax, deltay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    boxes = (
        {"x1": 618, "y1": 100, "x2": 693, "y2": 175, "width": 5, "fill": "white"},
        {"x1": 693, "y1": 100, "x2": 768, "y2": 175, "width": 5, "fill": "white"},
        {"x1": 618, "y1": 175, "x2": 693, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "green"},
        {"x1": 693, "y1": 175, "x2": 768, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "green"},
        {"x1": 618, "y1": 250, "x2": 693, "y2": 325, "width": 5, "fill": "blue"},
        {"x1": 693, "y1": 250, "x2": 768, "y2": 325, "width": 5, "fill": "blue"},
        {"x1": 618, "y1": 325, "x2": 693, "y2": 400, "width": 5, "fill": "yellow"},
        {"x1": 693, "y1": 325, "x2": 768, "y2": 400, "width": 5, "fill": "yellow"},
        {"x1": 543, "y1": 175, "x2": 618, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "dark orange"},
        {"x1": 468, "y1": 175, "x2": 543, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "dark orange"},
        {"x1": 768, "y1": 175, "x2": 843, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "red"},
        {"x1": 843, "y1": 175, "x2": 918, "y2": 250, "width": 5, "fill": "red"},
    )

    apps = (
        {"x": 125, "y": 125, "img": "np++.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"},
        {"x": 125, "y": 225, "img": "vim.png", "cmd": r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe"},
    )

    dnd = DragAndDrop(boxes, apps)
    dnd.run()
```

---

## Demo

Here's a quick run of the program on Windows. I open a couple text editors and check collision.

[image]